# Failed to get variables data inside if..else condition: "undefined err go"

Tags: http, go

I am trying to use HTTP Get with the use of `if..else` condition but I am getting an error:

> undefined: err go

This is my code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    num := 0
    if num == 0{
        resp, err := http.Get("https://httpbin.org/get")
    }else{
        resp, err := http.Get("https://google.com")
    }

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("error")
    }

    fmt.Println(resp.StatusCode)
}
```

I tried to defined the variables before the call:

```
var err error
var resp *http.Response
```

But then I received a different error:

> err declared and not used

Any idea how I can solve it and why it happens ?
Because any way the `resp` and `err` should be received by the `Get` request.

Comment: Pre-declare both variables before the `if` and inside the `if` / `else` blocks use `=` instead of `:=` to assign values to them.

Comment: @mkopriva works, write it as an answer and I will mark it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pre-declare both variables before the `if` and inside the `if` / `else` blocks use `=` instead of `:=` to assign values to them.

Read more here:

[Declarations and scope](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Declarations_and_scope)

[Variable declarations](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Variable_declarations)

[Short variable declarations](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Short_variable_declarations)